# How to use zip to generate a new archive but not just refresh files in the archive and add files into it, on linux?

Tags: linux, zip, archive, unzip

Here, (on linux)

there is an existing archive named A.zip, which include File1 and File2:

```
A.zip:
  File1
  File2
```

and I run this command: `zip A.zip File1 File3`, then the archive A.zip becomes like:

```
A.zip:
  File1
  File2
  File3
```

however, what I really want to get is a brand new archive A.zip! like:

```
A.zip:
  File1
  File3
```

I know it can be done by run `rm A.zip` and then run `zip A.zip File1 File3`, but it is not elegant and if I write these commands into a shell script so A.zip may not exist while the action to remove a non-existent file is not elegant as well.

Is there any options for me to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

Use these option to works:

```
zip -FSr A.zip File1 File3
```

OPTIONS

-FS

```
          Synchronize the contents of an archive with the files on the OS.  Normally when an archive is updated, new files are added and changed files are updated but files that no longer exist on  the
          OS  are  not deleted from the archive.  This option enables a new mode that checks entries in the archive against the file system.  If the file time and file size of the entry matches that of
          the OS file, the entry is copied from the old archive instead of being read from the file system and compressed.  If the OS file has changed, the entry is read and compressed  as  usual.   If
          the  entry in the archive does not match a file on the OS, the entry is deleted.  Enabling this option should create archives that are the same as new archives, but since existing entries are
          copied instead of compressed, updating an existing archive with -FS can be much faster than creating a new archive.  Also consider using -u for updating an archive.

          For this option to work, the archive should be updated from the same directory it was created in so the relative paths match.  If few files are being copied from the old archive,  it  may  be
          faster to create a new archive instead.

          Note  that  the timezone environment variable TZ should be set according to the local timezone in order for this option to work correctly.  A change in timezone since the original archive was
          created could result in no times matching and recompression of all files.

          This option deletes files from the archive.  If you need to preserve the original archive, make a copy of the archive first or use the --out option to output the  updated  archive  to  a  new
          file.  Even though it may be slower, creating a new archive with a new archive name is safer, avoids mismatches between archive and OS paths, and is preferred.
```

-r

```
          Travel the directory structure recursively; for example:

                 zip -r foo.zip foo

          or more concisely

                 zip -r foo foo

          In this case, all the files and directories in foo are saved in a zip archive named foo.zip, including files with names starting with ".", since the recursion does not use the  shell's  file-
          name  substitution  mechanism.  If you wish to include only a specific subset of the files in directory foo and its subdirectories, use the -i option to specify the pattern of files to be in‐
          cluded.  You should not use -r with the name ".*", since that matches ".."  which will attempt to zip up the parent directory (probably not what was intended).

          Multiple source directories are allowed as in

                 zip -r foo foo1 foo2

          which first zips up foo1 and then foo2, going down each directory.

          Note that while wildcards to -r are typically resolved while recursing down directories in the file system, any -R, -x, and -i wildcards are applied to internal archive pathnames once the di‐
          rectories  are  scanned.  To have wildcards apply to files in subdirectories when recursing on Unix and similar systems where the shell does wildcard substitution, either escape all wildcards
          or put all arguments with wildcards in quotes.  This lets zip see the wildcards and match files in subdirectories using them as it recurses.
```